# Can I add a constant with the constant of integration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose the the solution to the ordinary differential equation is

$$ y = x^2 + \ln(x) + 3 + C.$$

Can I simplify it to just

$$ y = x^2 + \ln(x) + C?$$

Comment: Yes. As long as you know the “C” are different values.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no initial/boundary conditions that restrict the values of the constant of integration into a certain range (a function's period, something positive/negative, a single value, etc.), then any other constants are irrelevant. If there ARE restrictions to the constant, you can either change those restrictions to reflect the addition of your other constant or you can leave both.